# fixed first TableRow android

Tags: android, tablerow, android-tablelayout

I have a table layout inside this table I defined a tablerow with 4 edittexts as columns headers.

My problem is that I want to make this static row as a fixed position, so while I scroll the screen down this row position doesn't changed.

I load the other rows dynamically from DB.

thank for help!

this is my xml code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewPhysicalExam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TableLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/TLArchiveHeader"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent">

                    <TableRow style="@style/HeaderRow">

                        <TextView
                        style="@style/HeaderText"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:text="Owner name"/>

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/HeaderText"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:text="Phone" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/HeaderText"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:text="Address" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/HeaderText"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:text="Mail" />
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/HeaderText"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:text="Fax" />

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: first of all...why are you using scrollview inside horizontalscrollview ? second of all..if you don't want a particular view to not scroll, just put it outside the scrollview.

Comment: I also trying to implement this with 2 tables, but it doesn't work well

Comment: do you have an image of the layout you are trying to achieve, so I can give you the right way to build it.

Comment: Thank you very much I succeeded.

Comment: my mistake was a beginner mistake. 
I did this with two tables and in the table below I defined an empty textviews like the headers.

Comment: if you fixed your issue, then post your correct code as a reference for future use.

Answer (score 3):

First of all,
Why do u need `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView`? 
`TableLayout` will spread rows vertically without `LinearLayout`.

Second - a ton of views will **significantly** slow down application performance. 
Consider replacing `TableLayout` to.. maybe a `ListView` or code your own component. As i understand you need a simple table with *text-only* fields - it's not so hard to implement a single, fast and simple to use component.

Third - the solution - just place header row outside ScrollView, like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/TLArchiveHeader"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TableRow style="@style/HeaderRow">
            <TextView
            style="@style/HeaderText"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:text="Owner name"/>
            <TextView
                style="@style/HeaderText"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:text="Phone" />
            <TextView
                style="@style/HeaderText"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:text="Address" />
            <TextView
                style="@style/HeaderText"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:text="Mail" />
            <TextView
                style="@style/HeaderText"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:text="Fax" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewPhysicalExam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TableLayout 
            android:id="@+id/TLArchiveRowPlaceholder"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Add rows to `TLArchiveRowPlaceholder`.

But in this case u need to have fixed widths of column. Or update header column widths after each main table update to not get headers misaligned.

Hope this helps.

My bad. 
Why answers were in comments? 
Didn't read them before =)